# ¿Cómo puedo generar notificaciones cuando se genera alguna excepción en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Tengo un script (Python 3.7) para llevar a cabo un experimento con equipos electrónicos. El script funciona bastante bien.

El problema reside en que en ocasiones los equipos no responden y se generan errores como SysError, KeyboardInterrupt o TimeOut.

He incorporado Pushsafer para que me envíe notificaciones al móvil cuando el script ha acabado. Lo que me gustaría es poder enviar notificaciones si alguno de esos "errores" ocurren.

Imagino que la idea general es empezar el script con ello:

```
if "SysError or KeyboardInterrupt or TimeOut":
    SendNotification()
    elif:
       #MyScript
```

Si me podéis echar una mano os lo agradecería

Comment: Échale un vistazo al manejo de excepciones en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Creo que te puede ayudar.

Comment: ¿qué tipo de notificaciones quieres?

Comment: Me refiero recibir notificaciones en el móvil. Pero eso ya lo he resuelto con la función PushNotification() y usando Slack.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto usando:

```
try:
    MainScript()
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    PushNotification("An ERROR has occured!!!")
    DoSomething1()
    DoAnotherThing()
```